# How to Set Background Color Of Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background

Hello I want to change Background Color of my Button Onclick Event on Runtime.

```
<Button FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,30,535" Name="b9" Width="96" Height="95" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="9" FontFamily="Verdana" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="Visible">
<Button.Template>
<ControlTemplate>
<Rectangle Name="myRectangle" RadiusX="46.5" RadiusY="46.5" Stroke="LightYellow" StrokeThickness="3">
<Rectangle.Fill>
<VisualBrush Opacity="0.7">
<VisualBrush.Visual>
<TextBlock Background="Green" Foreground="LightYellow" Name="myTextBlock" Padding="10">Change Color</TextBlock>
</VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
</Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Shape.Stroke" TargetName="myRectangle" Value="LightGreen" />
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" TargetName="myTextBlock">
<Setter.Value>
<LinearGradientBrush>
<GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="1" />
<GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5" />
<GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="0" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
</Button>
```

How i can get property of Background to set it On Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var textBlock = (TextBlock)b9.Template.FindName("myTextBlock", b9);
textBlock.Background = Brushes.Blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

**You could handle the Click event of the Button. The following code will switch its Background colour between Red and the default one when you click on it:**

> ```
>     <Button Content="test" Click="Button_Click_3">
>
>     </Button>
> ```

Here is the logic:

> private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> ```
>   {
>        Button btn = sender as Button;
>        btn.Background = btn.Background == Brushes.Red ? (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFDDDDDD")) : Brushes.Red;
>    }
> ```

**Or if you want do it in a Style, you should use an EventSetter:**

> ```
>         <Button.Style>
>             <Style TargetType="Button">
>                 <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click_3"/>
>             </Style>
>         </Button.Style>
>     </Button>
> ```